# SMC (Particle Filtering) code

Tags: forecasting, kalman-filter, filter, particle-filter

Does anyone know where I can find particle filtering code for R?  In particular I'm looking for code for filtering a forward-rate curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of reasonably well-commented code for implementing a simple bootstrap particle filter. It is fully implemented in R, so it is a good start for getting a sense of how the algorithm works if you want to tackle variations on basic bootstrap SMC. https://github.com/sbfnk/fitR/blob/master/R/smc.r

Answer (score 2):

I am under the impression that [RcppSMC](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.smc.html) is popular. I have never used it myself, so I cannot comment on it.

Edit: Other R packages I have heard of but also have never used: [Pomp](https://kingaa.github.io/pomp/), [RBi](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rbi/index.html) (from LibBi), and [RBiips](https://github.com/biips/rbiips) (from Biips). Also, there is my (much more modest) [software](https://github.com/tbrown122387/pf), which at the moment is c++ only, but that might change soon.